# Make vanilla js html table load faster

Tags: javascript, html, performance, html-table

I am trying to create an html table by fetching json from an api, but when it builds the table it takes a long time to populate, not because of the fetch request but because it is building a table with 600-1000 records and I want to speed it up.
I don't have much experience with js or html so its super rough code I just want to be able to speed it up. I have seen answers about adding pagination but I am not quite sure how to approach this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<head>
  <title>Example</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css">
</head>

<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-Ez0cGzNzHR1tYAv56860NLspgUGuQw16GiOOp/I2LuTmpSK9xDXlgJz3XN4cnpXWDmkNBKXR/VDMTCnAaEooxA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


  <label>
    Select a nurse:
    <select class="nurses" name="nurses">
      <option value="">Select One …</option>
      <option value="Om">Om</option>
      <option value="Reb">Reb</option>
      <option value="Man">Man</option>
      <option value="Gus">Gus</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <div class="result"></div>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Bed</th>
        <th scope="col">Patient</th>
        <th scope="col">Status</th>
        <th scope="col">Assigned Nurse ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Need Urgency</th>
        <th scope="col">Need</th>
        <th scope="col">Nurse</th>
        <th scope="col">Req ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Time Created Epoch</th>
        <th scope="col">Patient ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Time</th>
        <th scope="col">Room</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">
    </tbody>
  </table>





  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    const selectElement = document.querySelector('.nurses');
    var x = '';
    selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      const result = document.querySelector('.result');
      x = event.target.value;
      result.textContent = `You Chose ${event.target.value}`;

      getdata(x);
    });


    const tbody = document.querySelector('#tbody');

    const getdata = async () => {
      const endpoint = "https://my.api.here/beta?nurse=",
        response = await fetch(endpoint + x),
        data = await response.json(),
        Items = data.Items;
      tbody.innerHTML = "";
      Items.forEach(itemObj => {
        let { bed, patient_name, status, assigned_nurse_id, need_urgency, need, assigned_nurse, ID, timestamp_created_epoch, patient_id, timestamp_created, room } = itemObj;
        tbody.innerHTML += `<tr>
        <td>${bed}</td>
        <td>${patient_name}</td>
        <td>${status}</td>
        <td>${assigned_nurse_id}</td>
        <td>${need_urgency}</td>
        <td>${need}</td>
        <td>${assigned_nurse}</td>
        <td>${ID}</td>
        <td>${timestamp_created_epoch}</td>
        <td>${patient_id}</td>
        <td>${timestamp_created}</td>
        <td>${room}</td>

    </tr>`;
      });

      const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

      const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) =>
        v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
      )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

      // do the work...
      document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
        const table = th.closest('table');
        const tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
        Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr'))
          .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
          .forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr));
      })));

    }
  
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I suppose you could download all of the data, and paginate through it client-side. Even better would be that your API allows for pagination and only serves the data for a particular set of records that you request - maybe with a query field in the endpoint: `&page=1&limit=20` for example.

Comment: So you have three things here.... API call, building rows, DOM performance rendering it. The way you generate the rows is the big performance bottle neck. Build them as one string and then update the DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing innerHTML is a loop is one way to make your code render slow. Build a string and set that string one time.

```js
const items = data.Items;
const rows = items.map(itemObj => {
        let { bed, patient_name, status, assigned_nurse_id, need_urgency, need, assigned_nurse, ID, timestamp_created_epoch, patient_id, timestamp_created, room } = itemObj;
        return `<tr>
        <td>${bed}</td>
        <td>${patient_name}</td>
        <td>${status}</td>
        <td>${assigned_nurse_id}</td>
        <td>${need_urgency}</td>
        <td>${need}</td>
        <td>${assigned_nurse}</td>
        <td>${ID}</td>
        <td>${timestamp_created_epoch}</td>
        <td>${patient_id}</td>
        <td>${timestamp_created}</td>
        <td>${room}</td>
    </tr>`;
});
tbody.innerHTML = rows.join("");
```

Comment: Oh wow this drastically sped it up, thank you so much!